# How do you sort elements queried from multiple channels?

Tags: elementcriteriamodel, join, sorting

This is how I query elements from multiple channels:

```
{% set allEntries = craft.entries.section(['publication','text', 'exhibition']).limit(null) %}
```

I now want to sort all these entries by a custom date field. If all channels had the same date field, I would just append `order('releaseDate desc')` to the query.

But as I have chosen to set up individual date fields (i.e. `publicationReleaseDate`, `exhibitionOpeningDate`) I cannot figure out how to join and sort them.

Of course I could just use the same field in all channels, but then I can't have individual field names and instructions per channel.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [order param](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#order) sets the `ORDER BY` part of the MySQL query. You can also pass MySQL functions in it.

In your case [`GREATEST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) should do the job:

```
{% set allEntries = craft.entries
    .section(['publication','text', 'exhibition'])
    .order('GREATEST(releaseDate, publicationReleaseDate, exhibitionOpeningDate) desc')
    .limit(null) %}
```

Comment: This totally should work, except that there’s a bug in Craft that is preventing it. Just fixed it for the next release. In the meantime, you will just need to add “field_” to the beginning of the first field handle in that `GREATEST()` list, e.g. `GREATEST(field_releaseDate, publicationReleaseDate, exhibitionOpeningDate)`. (The next update won’t break that, just make it not necessary.)

Comment: Thanks @Brandon, already noticed that bug and added "field_" to all field handles.

Comment: As I had already merged all those date fields into one before asking this question, I can't say yet if this code is indeed working. Will do some testing tomorrow.

Comment: By "merged" I meant that I copied the content from the separate fields into one single field, that I now use in all channels. Didn't come around to do the testing yet. Sorry for delaying the answer accept.

Comment: @Brandon I could as well stick to a single field in all channels, but then I'd like to give this field a slightly different name and different instructions in the individual channels. Currently not possible, is it?

Comment: @ChristianSeelbach Nope that’s not currently possible. This use case makes a good argument for it, though.

Comment: I realize this questions is almost a decade old, but is this still supported in Craft 4? When I try this...

`{% for entry in craft.entries.section(['articles','podcasts']).orderby('GREATEST(postDate, featuredDate) desc').all() %}` I get a SQL error.